# package.json add "npm install -g" to scripts preinstall

Tags: node.js, package.json

When writing `package.json`:

`"scripts": {
    "preinstall": "npm install -g grunt-cli"
    },
  "devDependencies": {
    "async": "^0.9.0",
    "grunt": "^0.4.5",
    "grunt-contrib-connect": "^0.9.0",
    "grunt-contrib-cssmin": "^0.10.0",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "^0.10.0",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "^0.6.0",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "^0.6.1",
    "jit-grunt": "^0.9.0",
    "marked": "^0.3.2",
    "time-grunt": "^1.0.0",
    "underscore": "^1.7.0"
  }`

And then running the command `npm install`

It works on some computers but on some I get this error:
http://pastebin.com/rYUwhV5k

Is it proper use of the `package.json`?
Is there any other way to do it?
How can I fix the problem that occurs on the other computers?

Comment: You should not have a global install run as part of your preinstall. People won't realize it's there, get confused as to why a new global package is installed.

Answer (score 3):

According to the npm documentation "NOTE: INSTALL SCRIPTS ARE AN ANTIPATTERN"
https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts

In your case, probably best to just add in the readme.md that you need to have grunt installed to run the tests (and let the user decides how to install it)

Comment: it looks like they've since removed that warning.

Comment: Yet another failing of npm. Not long 'till someone releases an alternative.